# How to get Stripe invoice's billing period?

Tags: stripe-payments

As the title suggests, I need to get an invoice's billing period. `period_start` and `period_end` are inadequate because the first invoice of a subscription's billing cycle has the same timestamp for both. Also, those timestamps are for the period in which invoice items were added to the invoice, not to show which period the invoice encompasses.

I need to see what dates the invoice applies to. For instance, the first invoice's billing period would be from the start of their subscription to the millisecond before the next invoice is generated. That kind of thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want the `period` of the subscription(s) line item(s) on the invoice. You'd retrieve the invoice via the [API](https://stripe.com/docs/api#retrieve_invoice) and then you would loop over the invoice items. You would find one with the `type` [property](https://stripe.com/docs/api#invoice_line_item_object-type) set to `subscription` which indicates this line item corresponds to the subscription you just charged for.

You can then look at the `period` hash with `period[start]` and `period[end]` to know which period you just invoiced for.

Comment: I thought about this, but doesn't Stripe allow multiple subscription line items now?

Comment: @trevorhinesley they do but they would all be on the same billing cycle so finding the first one would be enough.

Comment: I know this is an old thread. But just wanted to add that using line item's period[start] is also NOT reliable, because you may have prorated items from the last billing cycle and then the first item's period[start] would be some date in the last billing cycle.  It is probably better to just use 'created' as start date and then add your billing cycle ( typically 1month ) to get the end date.